# Periodic bounded solution to this PDE has necessarily mean zero

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, fluid-dynamics

Consider the fractional KdV equation:
$$ u_t + L_\alpha u_x + u u_x = 0,$$
where $L_\alpha$ denotes the Fourier multiplier operator with symbol $m(k) = |k|^\alpha$, $\alpha < -1$.  I'm interest in $2\pi$-periodic traveling-wave solution $u(t,x) = \phi(x - ct)$, where $c > 0$ is the speed of the right-propagating wave.  In this framework, the above equation becomes
$$ -c \phi + L_\alpha \phi + \frac{1}{2} \phi^2 = B,$$
where $B \in \mathbb{R}$ is an integration constant.

**Claim**: Since the symbol of $L_\alpha$ is homogeneous, any bounded solution of the above equation has necessarily zero mean.

I'm not sure what this claim means.  Does it mean that if $\phi$ is a $2\pi$-periodic solution, then we must have:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \phi(x) \,dx = 0 \;?$$
How can I prove it?  I tried to put the equation in Fourier transform, but it did not help much.

Thank you.